# Improve charts generation speed/time (charts.js)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, charts

I'm looking for some advice, to be specific in the generation of data using phpmyadmin and mysql.

I have a website (local) that register ideas from different people, those ideas are registered in a database.

I'm able to retrieve all the data into a table that i have in a reports section, the problem is that when there are at least 1500 records it gets slow (i know the amount of data printed in the table makes it slow).

I generate some charts from that data using charts.js, which is good until there are a lot of records in the webpage. (I tested putting 5000 records, 1500 records, and 2000 (which is the max amount we get with this ideas)).

So, what do I want to know?

1. What is an efficient way of showing that amount of data to the user without the page getting extremely slow.
2. What is the best practice to generate charts, from a table that gets its data from database or directly getting the data from the database, if so, which chart framework would you recommend?

I have read about pagination, to retrieve just part of the data by page, but my export to excel use the table data to export it, so it would ruin the exporting option.

I'm really sorry if this is no place for asking this programming question, but I cant think of a way of doing this in an efficient way.

Here is a picture of part of my webpage (in top you can see some charts), (below you can see some records of the table), the middle is just some report generation from the date/week and the export to excel option.

[image: records view of my webpage]

Tech used in the webpage:

PHP
JQUERY
HTML5
CSS3
mysql

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to display each individual data point in your charts? Or are you just displaying totals/sums/avg/etc?

Comment: Not individual data points. (thanks God).
Just general graphics from the data i have in the table.

Example.

Lets say i have 10 records of different ideas:

3 ideas approved
3 ideas rejected
4 ideas under verification.

The charts shows the sum of each idea's status, but never individual records.